# Add search to existing dropdown button in flutter app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, search, drop-down-menu

I have implemented a list of dropdown from api. But now i want to implement search option to it.
the dropdown shows a list of countries with country name and flag from api.
Can anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

This is the code for the current dropdown button :

```
  Card( margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
 child: Container(
 padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric( horizontal: screenWidth * 0.05), 
child: Obx( () {
 return DropdownButton<String>(
 value: countryController.countryName.value,
 isExpanded: true, 
icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_outlined), 
iconSize: screenWidth * 0.06, elevation: 16,
 // isDense: true,
 underline: Container( color: Colors.transparent, ),
 onChanged: (String value) { countryController.selectIntlCountry(value);                    
 },
                          items: countryController.countryList
                              .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                                  (CountryModel item) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: item.countryName,
                              child: Container(
                                // width: 250,
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Image.network(
                                      item.flagUrl,
                                      width: screenWidth * 0.09,
                                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(width: screenWidth * 0.03),
                                    Expanded(
                                        child: Text(
                                      item.countryName,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: screenWidth * 0.045,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                    )),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        );
                      
                      },
                    )),
              ),
```

I have tried using dropdown_search package. But unsuccessful in implementing it right.